# Add custom block below mage_catalog_block_product_price

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to add a custom block below mage_catalog_block_product_price and show it on list.phtml (category page) and view.phtml (product page). (Magento 1.9.x)

I was trying to add to my local.xml

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <block type="core/template" name="shippinginfo" template="mytemp/shipping.phtml" after="Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price" /> 
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

It is not working unfortunately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try without using layout file like this.First
open list.ptml file and search line `$this->getPriceHtml`.
After that line you have to just add following code:-

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('mytemp/shipping.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for the category page. Could you please tell me in which file I have to put it for the product page itself? Thx

Comment: For product detail page you have to add code after  $this->getPriceHtml in app\design\frontend\theme_package\theme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml file.

Comment: Thanks. I also got my initial try working. All I had to do was to add getChildChildHtml to list.phtml and view.phtml. In view.phtml I did not find $this->getPriceHtml though. I had to put it out of the price block which gives a little bit of margin. Maybe I can fix this. Not sure how, though.